# Java this parameter

Tags: java, reference, this

Quick question, I tried to find a satisfactory answer on my own.

Say I have 2 classes Object1 and Object2. Now I want Object2 to do use Object1's resources so I do this

```
Object1 obj1;
    public Object2(Object1 o){
        obj1 = o;
    }
```

and in Object1 I do this

```
new Object2(this);
```

Does this give each `Object2` an `Object1`, or does it simply point to the Object1 as expected?

Comment: Please show a **complete** code-snippet.  I have no idea what's calling what here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will point to `Object1` as expected. This is because Java stores object variables as "references"("pointers" if you like thinking in C) and, when you pass this reference by value, you are giving the function the objects reference..  There is a good basic tutorial on this functionality [here](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javaqa/2000-05/03-qa-0526-pass.html). Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you very much. I was worried that I'd be doing wayyy more processing than expected, this is good news.

Answer (score 1):

It simply uses a reference (points) to Object1. Whenever you change `o` in `Object2` class, you will be changing original `obj1` object also.

Answer (score 0):

you can use IS-A relationship

> Object2 extends Object1{ }

so now Object2 can use Object2 resources as well as Object1 resources. suppose you want vise versa, you can use HAS-A relationship

Object1 has Object2 reference like this

> Object1{ Object2 obj2; }

Object2 has Object1 reference like this

> Object2{ Object1 obj1; }